# How to run app without storyboard?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, appdelegate

New to Xcode 8 and Swift 3. Any help would be much appreciated. I've been doing as much research as possible but I'm still having trouble running my app without using the storyboard. Seems I get a black screen when I launch it in the simulator due to:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </User...........................app> (loaded)' with name '`main`''
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104099b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000101379141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104102625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   UIKit                               0x0000000102676e74 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 501
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000102679614 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 222
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010226f7ea -[UIApplication _loadMainNibFileNamed:bundle:] + 75
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010226fe13 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 260
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010226e4b6 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1407
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010226b7f3 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 182
    9   FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001057845f6 __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 24
    10  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000010578446d -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 186
    11  FrontBoardServices                  0x00000001057847f6 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 45
    12  CoreFoundation                      0x000000010403fc01 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    13  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040250cf __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 527
    14  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001040245ff __CFRunLoopRun + 911
    15  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000104024016 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 406
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010226a08f -[UIApplication _run] + 468
    17  UIKit                               0x0000000102270134 UIApplicationMain + 159
    18  testappfour                         0x0000000100da2c57 main + 55
    19  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010501b65d start + 1
    20  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
import UIKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()

        window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())
        return true
    }
```

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

1) In project settings remove storyboard for 'Main Storyboard' setting

[image]

2) There is a typo in your code. View controller class is named ViewController but you instantiate ViewContoller ('r' is missed).

After doing those both things your code works well for me and project runs:
[image]

Comment: It should not compile if he has done typo in code too.

Comment: @vivek, you're right. I just wanted to point out what exactly I had to change to make the example work.

Answer (score 1):

Check General>Deployment Info> Main Interface has still pointing to Main.storyboard? If yes remove it.

Comment: Thank you, Vivek. Already deleted "main" in the via general>Deployment Info. Turns out I did not delete the Main.storyboard file in my folder.